# Find and update a collection in JSONB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have a Rails 5.0 app with a JSONB column called `data`, which contains an array of hashes:

```
[
    {'event': 'web_session', 'user_id': 1, 'count': 13},
    {'event': 'web_session', 'user_id': 2, 'count': 10},
    {'event': 'web_session', 'user_id': 3, 'count': 42}
]
```

How would I update one of the hashes, e.g. matching `'user_id': 2`, with a different `count` value?

Is this the most efficient way (I'd potentially have ~1 million hashes):

```
h = data.find {|h| h['user_id'] == 2}
h['count'] = 43
save
```

Comment: Yes, this is most efficient way to find the record in JSONB

Comment: *I'd potentially have ~1 million hashes* ... in a single `jsonb` cell? Are you sure you want to go with this DB design?